# How to use the result from last calculation in a new calculation in wcalc?

Tags: shell, calculator

In `wcalc` how can I do something like

```
-> 1+2
 = 3
-> X+1
 = 4
```

where `X` equals the result of the last calculation (that is 3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special variable `a` contains the result of the last answer

```
-> 1 + 2
 = 3
-> a + 5
 = 8
->
```

From the [`wcalc` README file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/w-calc/files/Wcalc/2.4.1/README/download)

> Some special notes about variables - two things are reserved:
>
> - a - this variable represents the last answer, and may be used in expressions.
> - q - this variable is reserved in the command-line version (it means quit), and cannot be used in expressions.
>
> Also, built-in constants cannot be re-defined, although they are
> treated as variables in all other cases.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `help` command, the last answer is stored in the variable `a`.

```
-> 1+2
  = 3
-> a+1
  = 4
```

You can also use any other variable to store intermediate result:

```
-> X=1+2
 X = 3
-> X=X+1
 X = 4
```